# IBM MobileFirst 8.0 cordova android mfp-push plugin not supported anymore?

Tags: android, ionic3, ibm-mobilefirst

I can not build android version of my IMF + IonicV3 (cordova) project.

I tested this also on clean version (empty project, added mfp plugin build ok, next added mfp-push and build is impossible on android)

***Environment***:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.7.1

Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

cordova : 7.1.0

Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1

NodeJS            : v10.8.0

npm               : 6.5.0

cordova-plugin-mfp ^8.0.2018112111

cordova-plugin-mfp-push ^8.0.2018122606

***Problem***

> Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but
>   primary configuration failure takes precedence.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
>     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:645)
>     at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
>     at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'Test/platforms/android/cordova-plugin-mfp-push/starter-build-extras.gradle'
>     line: 14
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating script.
>
>   > Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: Whats your gradle configuration?

Comment: Gradle 5.0
Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4
Kotlin:       1.3.10
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle ( app level and root level)?

Comment: gradleVersion = '4.1.0'

Comment: Complete shot in the dark, but maybe try adding a more recent android platform.  I had a similar problem (with a different push plugin), and adding android@6.4.0 resolved it.